# PHP preg_replace a part of JSON content

Tags: php, json

I've got the following JSON string:

```
{
    "time":"321321545646",
    "documents":[
        {"name":"name1","body":"HASH_BASE64 1"},
        {"name":"name2","body":"HASH_BASE64 2"}
    ]
}
```

In real production use, the "HASH BASE64" will be base64 encoded string. 
How can I replace content of **each** "body" tag with string = "LONGSTRING", to receive something like this:

```
{
    "time":"321321545646",
    "documents":[
        {"name":"name1","body":"LONGSTRING"},
        {"name":"name2","body":"LONGSTRING"}
    ]
}
```

?

Comment: Definitely not with `preg_replace`

Comment: Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode the JSON to arrays, modify the values, use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode it back as JSON.

Comment: @MacBooc how is related to JSON the question you linked?

Comment: my bad was thinking about regex to detect base64 in a string while i saw preg_replace in the title

Answer (score 1):

You Don't Need `preg-replace()` Just Decode Your json by `json_decode()`

Then Loop Through The json Document And change Each Document data Like So:

```
$json = json_decode('{
    "time":"321321545646",
    "documents":[
        {"name":"name1","body":"HASH_BASE64 1"},
        {"name":"name2","body":"HASH_BASE64 2"}
    ]
}');
foreach ($json->documents as $document){
    $document->body = "LONGSTRING";
}
dump($json);
```

This Is The Output :

```
{#229 ▼
  +"time": "321321545646"
  +"documents": array:2 [▼
    0 => {#228 ▼
      +"name": "name1"
      +"body": "LONGSTRING"
    }
    1 => {#227 ▼
      +"name": "name2"
      +"body": "LONGSTRING"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't do it with regular expressions but by decoding, changing the data and encoding again:

```
$data = json_decode($json);

for($i = 0; $i < count($data->documents); $i++) {
    $data->documents[$i]->body = "LONGSTRING";
}

$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: There is a reason I would like to use regular expressions: this JSON is part of comunication logs and I'd like to have it saved without any more changes. Additionally, in some cases it doesn't have to be a proper JSON string, it might have some errors.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use regular expressions to modify JSON data - PHP has native functions for parsing and encoding it. See http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "time":"321321545646",
    "documents":[
        {"name":"name1","body":"HASH_BASE64 1"},
        {"name":"name2","body":"HASH_BASE64 2"}
    ]
}';

// Decode JSON into a native PHP object structure
$decoded = json_decode($json);

// Loop over each element, and modify the body
$decoded->documents = array_map(function ($document) {
    $document->body = 'LONGSTRING';
    return $document;
}, $decoded->documents);

// Re-encode
echo json_encode($decoded);
```